# Error with DocumentRoot in new Vagrant

Tags: apache, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm attempting to use Jeffrey Way's Vagrant setup (https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Vagrant-Setup) and it almost works for me on a Mac running Yosemite.  When Apache restarts at the very end, I get an error stating:

```
==> default: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html] does not exist
==> default: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Prior to that in his install.sh, he's deleting the html directory and doing a symlink it looks like (I'm new to this, sorry).

To fix it, I ssh into Vagrant, edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and change the DocumentRoot from /var/www/html to just /var/www and then I'm able to view my site on localhost:8080.

How should I be doing this though so it just works out of the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below line after the line `sudo ln -fs /vagrant/public /var/www` (#38) in `install.sh`

```
sed -i "s#DocumentRoot /var/www/html#DocumentRoot /var/www#g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Running the updated install script should automatically replace the DocumentRoot from `/var/www/html` to just `/var/www`

Comment: Worked great, thank you!  My only question though is why I had to do that.  I guess I'm confused as to why it didn't work without it or why he's deleting the html part of the directory?

Comment: I haven't fully gone through the script, but I thought you wanted the change.

Comment: Very true but mostly I was hoping to learn why we're changing the /html by removing it with the RF and then having to change it with your fix.  I guess that part just doesn't make sense to me.